# How can i convert color picker value to a web or rgb or any Color class compatible type?

Tags: javafx, colors, rgb, graphicscontext

My color picker in javaFX returns something like `0x000000ff`. How to convert this to web colors, either rgb or hex?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this for rgb values is right in the javadoc for [ColorPicker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ColorPicker.html):

```
final ColorPicker colorPicker = new ColorPicker();
colorPicker.setOnAction(new EventHandler() {
    public void handle(Event t) {
        Color c = colorPicker.getValue();
        System.out.println("New Color's RGB = "+c.getRed()+" "+c.getGreen()+" "+c.getBlue());
    }
});
```

Or you can get the color as a hex string for the above sample using:

```
String hexString = c.toString();
```

Comment: Sure .. I've looked in to that. but the methods "get" returns only a none rgb value mostly 1 and 0 after casting to int.
and ofc.  toString returns hex, but it's not a hex color value that can be used into forexample CSS so that's why i'm confused.

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/paint/Color.html#getRed--). The `getRed()`, `getGreen()` and `getBlue()` methods return `double`s in the range 0.0-1.0. So if you cast to `int`, of course you get either `0` or `1`. If you want an `int` in the range 0-255 do `(int)(c.getRed() * 255)`.